# Skip Output as default value for QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Is it possible to set the *[Skip Output]* behaviour as the default for a QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination parameter in a processing script?

[image]

I've tried using a None value for the defaultValue parameter, but it remains set as *[Save to temporary file]*.

```
self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(
            self.EXPORT_PATH,
            'Export JSON file',
            fileFilter='JSON files (*.json)',
            optional=True,
            defaultValue=None
            
        )
    )
```